# 3-tier architecture programming I have eclipse and tomcat that are connected,it gives me 404 error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat8

hi I am working a project using eclipse and tomcat 8 
I have an index.html that is working properly but when i press one of the submit buttons, I have an 404 error and I don't know how to fix it.I think that my code is correct.I have make  a server  with no coding errors.I think that the problem is on the connection of tomcat with my database.I will appreciate every help can anyone gives me.If you want to see my code i can upload it.thanks

Comment: 404 is the "page not found" error and has nothing to do with the database.

Comment: my dbservlet is  correct but  is  still  giving me  404  error  and  not  the  messages  I expect . I have  seen some videos  for  tomcat  configuration but  they don't  help  me.

Comment: I think you should post more details about your application.